# R markdown/shiny: fileInput in one shiny code chunk, then reuse the data in the next (non-shiny and shiny) chunks

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm working on a rmd file with `output: html_document` and `runtime: shiny` in the header. Now I have a code chunk that uses shiny and that contains a fileInput element:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(4, offset = 8,
             fileInput("upload", NULL, buttonLabel = "upload", placeholder = "file.csv")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    df <- reactive({
      req(input$upload)
      # Import data
      vroom::vroom(input$upload$datapath, delim = ",")
    })
  }
)
```

Later in rmd file, I'd like to reuse the uploaded data for non-shiny and shiny chunks.

I tried to assign it to a global variable using `df <<- reactive({` with no luck and also tried to add the following code in the server part:

```
    observe({
      if (!is.null(input$upload)) {
        assign("df", df(), envir = .GlobalEnv)
      }
    })
```

If I have another chunk like:

```
if (!is.null(df)) {
  head(df)
} else {
  cat("No file uploaded yet.")
}
```

it works when each code chunk is run manually, but not if I click on "Run Document" in RStudio. I could put all code in one chunk, but I'm using rmd, because I have lots of text between the chunks.

How can I reuse the uploaded data in independent code chunks? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the uploaded dataset is assigned to a reactive object, the only way to reuse it across the rest of the document is to feed it into other reactive objects.

Here's a reprex showing how you can do that:

````
---
title: "Reuse fileInput"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
date: "2023-06-13"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
```

## Data Upload

```{r}
fluidRow(
  column(
    width = 12,
    fileInput(
      inputId = "upload",
      label = NULL,
      buttonLabel = "upload",
      placeholder = "file.csv",
      width = "100%"
    )
  )
)

df <- reactive({
  req(input$upload)
  # Import data
  vroom::vroom(input$upload$datapath, delim = ",")
})
```


## Other Parts

Since we assign the uploaded dataset to a reactive object, the only way
to reuse it across the rest of the document is to feed it into other
reactive objects.

Here are few examples of how you can do that:

### Preview

Here we use `render*` directly without using `output$outputId`:

```{r}
DT::renderDT({
  df()
})
```


### Summary

You can as well use functions from shiny, like so:

```{r}
output$summary <- renderPrint({
  summary(df())
})

fluidRow(
  column(
    width = 12,
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "summary")
  )
)
```

### By 100

Let's multiply all numeric columns in the dataset by 100:

```{r}
library(dplyr)

by_100 <- reactive({
  df() %>%
    mutate(
      across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x * 100)
    )
})

DT::renderDT(by_100())
```
````